# Partial View loading wrong model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in which I have a model specified as such:

```
@model IEnumerable<AbstractThinking2015.Models.BlogModel>

@foreach (var item in Model.Take(5))
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.BlogModelId })</li>
}
```

And I'm calling this using:

```
<div class="widget">
   <h4>Recent Posts</h4>
   <ul>
      @Html.Partial("View")
   </ul>
</div>
```

But I'm getting the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'AbstractThinking2015.Models.BlogModel', but this dictionary requires
>   a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AbstractThinking2015.Models.BlogModel]'.

I'm sure this is because the model being passed into the view is the single blog but I want to use the list that's defined in the partial view. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is your main view rendering ?

Comment: At the moment it's just breaking but the Model it's using is: @model AbstractThinking2015.Models.BlogModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not pass a model t the partial explicitly, It will take the model of the parent view. So from your error message, It is clear that you are passing a single object of the BlogModel to your view from your action method, hence getting the error.

You need to make sure that your main view (where you are calling the partial), is also strongly typed to a collection of `BlogModel` objects.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var blogList=new List<Models.BlogModel>(); 
  // or you may read from db and load the blogList variable

  return View(blogList);
}
```

And the Index view, where you are calling the Partial will be strongly typed to a collection of `BlogModel`.

```
@model List<Models.BlogModel>
<h1>Index page which will call Partial</h1>
<div class="widget">
   <h4>Recent Posts</h4>
   <ul>
      @Html.Partial("View")
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is correct explanation OP is likely looking for something like `@Html.Partial("View", Model.RecentPosts)` rather than rendering current post as list of recent posts.

Comment: I agree that he should have a view model which has a RecentPosts property which he should be passing to the partial. From his original post,It is not clear what he is trying to do with the index view. So i don't know what view model he really should use for his index view !